Alternative to Arc<Mutex> and clone() when using multiple variables in a callback
I'm new to Rust, and I'm working on an exercise to develop a parking lot system using the Raspberry Pi GPIO and socket.io.
After some struggle, I managed to create a program that actually works, but I found the code to be very repetitive when it comes to moving outer variables into a callback.
I do want to know if there is a better way to do this (without cloning every variable that I need to use in every callback I define). Additionally, I want to know how I can define this callback in another module (ideally using "pub fn"), because right now I have a lot of callbacks inside the main function.
That's my code for reference:
mod model;

use crate::model::{Car, ParkingLot};
use ctrlc;
use rppal::gpio::{Gpio, Level, Trigger};
use rust_socketio::ClientBuilder;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering::SeqCst};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    // Handling Ctrl-C
    let running = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(true));
    let r = running.clone();
    ctrlc::set_handler(move || {
        println!("Received Ctrl-C, shutting down...");
        r.store(false, SeqCst);
    })
    .unwrap();

    // Setting up GPIO pins
    let gpio = Gpio::new().unwrap();

    let mut entry_open_signal = gpio.get(23).unwrap().into_input_pulldown();
    let mut entry_close_signal = gpio.get(24).unwrap().into_input_pulldown();
    let entry_engine = Arc::new(Mutex::new(gpio.get(10).unwrap().into_output_low()));
    let mut exit_open_signal = gpio.get(25).unwrap().into_input_pulldown();
    let mut exit_close_signal = gpio.get(12).unwrap().into_input_pulldown();
    let exit_engine = Arc::new(Mutex::new(gpio.get(17).unwrap().into_output_low()));
    let space_address_1 = Arc::new(Mutex::new(gpio.get(22).unwrap().into_output_low()));
    let space_address_2 = Arc::new(Mutex::new(gpio.get(26).unwrap().into_output_low()));
    let space_address_3 = Arc::new(Mutex::new(gpio.get(19).unwrap().into_output_low()));
    let space_sensor = Arc::new(Mutex::new(gpio.get(18).unwrap().into_input_pulldown()));
    let closed_signal = Arc::new(Mutex::new(gpio.get(27).unwrap().into_output_low()));

    // Setting up the socket.io client
    let closed_signal_clone_1 = closed_signal.clone();
    let closed_signal_clone_2 = closed_signal.clone();
    let client = Arc::new(Mutex::new(
        ClientBuilder::new("http://localhost:3000")
            .on("connect", |_, _| println!("Connected to the server"))
            .on("disconnect", |_, _| {
                println!("Disconnected from the server")
            })
            .on("close_parking_lot", move |_, _| {
                closed_signal_clone_1.lock().unwrap().set_high();
            })
            .on("open_parking_lot", move |_, _| {
                closed_signal_clone_2.lock().unwrap().set_low();
            })
            .connect()
            .unwrap(),
    ));

    // Creating the parking lot
    let parking_lot = Arc::new(Mutex::new(ParkingLot::new()));

    // Callback to turn on the entry engine when the entry open signal is triggered
    let entry_engine_clone = entry_engine.clone();
    entry_open_signal
        .set_async_interrupt(Trigger::RisingEdge, move |_| {
            entry_engine_clone.lock().unwrap().set_high()
        })
        .unwrap();

    // Callback to turn off the entry engine when the entry close signal is triggered
    let entry_engine_clone = entry_engine.clone();
    let parking_lot_clone = parking_lot.clone();
    let space_address_1_clone = space_address_1.clone();
    let space_address_2_clone = space_address_2.clone();
    let space_address_3_clone = space_address_3.clone();
    let space_sensor_clone = space_sensor.clone();
    let client_clone = client.clone();
    entry_close_signal
        .set_async_interrupt(Trigger::RisingEdge, move |_| {
            // Turn off the entry engine
            entry_engine_clone.lock().unwrap().set_low();

            // Wait for the car to find a parking space
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));

            // after the entry is closed, scan the parking lot to check if a car entered in a parking space
            let mut car_inserted: Option<Car> = None;

            for address in 0..8 {
                let (address_1, address_2, address_3) = convert_address_to_levels(address as u8);

                space_address_1_clone.lock().unwrap().write(address_1);
                space_address_2_clone.lock().unwrap().write(address_2);
                space_address_3_clone.lock().unwrap().write(address_3);

                // Wait the sensor to stabilize
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));

                let parking_space = &mut parking_lot_clone.lock().unwrap().spaces[address];

                // if the space is occupied and there was no car in the parking space database,
                // then the car entered in the parking space
                if space_sensor_clone.lock().unwrap().is_high() && parking_space.car.is_none() {
                    let car = Car::new();
                    parking_space.car = Some(car.clone());
                    car_inserted = Some(car);
                }
            }

            // if a car entered in a parking space, send a signal to the server
            if let Some(car) = car_inserted {
                // send signal to server
                client_clone
                    .lock()
                    .unwrap()
                    .emit("car_inserted", serde_json::to_string(&car).unwrap())
                    .unwrap();
            }
        })
        .unwrap();

    // Callback to turn on the exit engine when the exit open signal is triggered
    let exit_engine_clone = exit_engine.clone();
    let parking_lot_clone = parking_lot.clone();
    let space_address_1_clone = space_address_1.clone();
    let space_address_2_clone = space_address_2.clone();
    let space_address_3_clone = space_address_3.clone();
    let space_sensor_clone = space_sensor.clone();
    let client_clone = client.clone();
    exit_open_signal
        .set_async_interrupt(Trigger::RisingEdge, move |_| {
            // Turn on the exit engine
            exit_engine_clone.lock().unwrap().set_high();

            // after the exit is opened, scan the parking lot to check if a car left a parking space
            let mut car_removed: Option<Car> = None;

            for address in 0..8 {
                let (address_1, address_2, address_3) = convert_address_to_levels(address as u8);

                space_address_1_clone.lock().unwrap().write(address_1);
                space_address_2_clone.lock().unwrap().write(address_2);
                space_address_3_clone.lock().unwrap().write(address_3);

                // Wait the sensor to stabilize
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));

                let parking_space = &mut parking_lot_clone.lock().unwrap().spaces[address];

                // if the space is empty and there was a car in the parking space database,
                // then the car left the parking space
                if space_sensor_clone.lock().unwrap().is_low() && parking_space.car.is_some() {
                    let car = parking_space.car.take().unwrap();
                    car_removed = Some(car);
                }
            }

            // if a car left the parking space, send a signal to the server
            if let Some(car) = car_removed {
                // send signal to server
                client_clone
                    .lock()
                    .unwrap()
                    .emit("car_removed", serde_json::to_string(&car).unwrap())
                    .unwrap();
            }
        })
        .unwrap();

    // Callback to turn off the exit engine when the exit close signal is triggered
    let exit_engine_clone = exit_engine.clone();
    exit_close_signal
        .set_async_interrupt(Trigger::RisingEdge, move |_| {
            exit_engine_clone.lock().unwrap().set_low();
        })
        .unwrap();

    println!("Program running");

    // Waiting for Ctrl-C
    while running.load(SeqCst) {}

    println!("Program terminated");
}

fn convert_address_to_levels(address: u8) -> (Level, Level, Level) {
    let address_1 = if address & 0b001 != 0 {
        Level::High
    } else {
        Level::Low
    };

    let address_2 = if address & 0b010 != 0 {
        Level::High
    } else {
        Level::Low
    };

    let address_3 = if address & 0b100 != 0 {
        Level::High
    } else {
        Level::Low
    };

    (address_1, address_2, address_3)
}


Titles should be what the application does, not the specific code you want reviewed. Something like "Parking Lot Management System in Rust".

Instead of all the variables as seperate Arc<Mutex<...>> but them in a struct and put that struct in a single Arc<Mutex<...>>>
